# Bounded sequence of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Here is a page of my teacher's lectures on bounded sequences.

[The Lecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCn6n.jpg)

On the top of the graphs. He defines bounded and uniformly bounded sequence of functions then he gives some examples.

Bounded if: $\forall x \in D$, $\exists M_{x} \in R$ such that $|f_{n}(x)|<M_{x}$, $\forall n \in N$,

Uniformly Bounded if: $\exists M \in R$ such that $|f_{n}(x)|<M$, $\forall n \in N$, $\forall x \in D$

I am very confused as to why in example (A)

$f_n (x)=\frac{1}{n\,x}$ is bounded for  $x\in(0,1]$

but for example (F)

$f_n (x)=x+\frac{1}{n}$ is not bounded $x\in R$

but since $0\notin(0,1]$ and $\infty\notin R$, why is (A) bounded but (F) not bounded?

Comment: what norm are you using?

Comment: @dREaM, what do you mean?

Comment: Can you add the definition of bounded he actually uses?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk, its on the top of the page http://i.stack.imgur.com/xCn6n.jpg.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk, $\forall x \in D$, $\exists M_{x} \in R$ such that $|f_{n}(x)|<M_{x}$, $\forall n \in N$, $\forall x \in D$

Comment: I think that this is likely an error since for (F), $|f_n(x)|<1+|x|$ for all $x$.